# HTMLENTITIES doesn't work with cyrillics

Tags: php, html-entities

How can I make htmlentities to work with cyrillic symbols.
Now, when I try input some cyrillic: "Тест" it returns "Ð¢ÐµÑ"
My code:
    $var = htmlentities($var);
Encoding: utf-8.
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need HTML entities in the first place? If you have UTF-8 output, displaying the actual characters should work fine.

Comment: I want my users not to enter HTML code in their comments

Comment: would `htmlspecialchars()` not be enough for that? It would circumvent the cyrillic issue completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bring closure to this question -

> I want my users not to enter HTML code in their comments

This is not necessary; `htmlspecialchars()` will convert all special characters necessary to prevent HTML from being shown.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, try this solution:

```
<?php echo htmlentities("Текст на русском языке", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
```

Comment: the output is "Текст на русском языке" :/

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is ENT_HTML401, which contains only a few entities. Try using ENT_HTML5:

```
<?php echo htmlentities("Текст на русском языке", ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8') ?>
```

If you want to know which entities are replaced, you can use get_html_translation_table:

```
<?php print_r(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401)) ?>
<?php print_r(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5)) ?>
```